# MySQL is slow SELECT to find a single-digit numeric value on a large InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, query-optimization

I have a simple key-value store table with 85M rows, file size of 5GB. (Wordpress postmeta table.)

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191)),
  KEY `meta_value` (`meta_value`(100)),
  KEY `meta_value_len_10` (`meta_value`(10)),
  KEY `meta_value_len_1` (`meta_value`(1))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta        
WHERE meta_key = "case"
AND meta_value = "359976";
```

The lookup is fast, under 50ms. It uses the meta_value index as expected and can narrow the scan to 4 rows (as shown in EXPLAIN). As I reduce the number of digits in meta_value's target value, the row scan might increase to a few hundred, which is still trivial.

The problem case -- the only case in which the query runs terribly slow (10+ seconds) -- is when the target value is both **one character in length and a numeric value**; basically, if it is 0 through 9 only. Then, the query goes into a scan of 400,000 rows. If I use a one-character alpha letter instead, the query is fine, which befuddles me.

**Problem case:**

```
SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta        
WHERE meta_key = "case"
AND meta_value = "5";
```

The other difference behind the scenes, is that the problem query is the only kind that utilizes the meta_value_len_10 index. All others (including single-digit alpha) use the vanilla meta_value index.

Even when I run a **FORCE INDEX(meta_key,meta_value_len_1)** to target that single digit, it makes no difference. I also tried creating a 4-character-long index, but it made no difference.

Note that, in any scenario, EXPLAIN always shows "using where" as the lookup method. No "using filesort" or anything that would indicate disk I/O (except for the sheer number of rows in the problem case).

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

[MySQL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: Thanks, I added in table size and specific query times. I thought it was implied that since I'm talking about proper indexing, we all know the speed difference can be 5 to 10x between undesired and desired performance.

Comment: That is a generic comment to help user improve their question. For your case the most important is you didnt inlcude the EXPLAIN results for your test.

Comment: Yet another reason why key-value schema sucks.

Comment: @RickJames: Just one small example of the kind of *joy* we experience when working with an EAV model.

Answer (score 2):

For better performance of that query, consider adding an index (a KEY), e.g.

```
... ON (`meta_key`(191), `meta_value`(10), `post_id`)
```

MySQL is only going to use one index for the query.  With equality predicates (equal comparisons in the WHERE clause) on both the `meta_key` and `meta_value` columns, we'd want those to be leading columns in the index.

My inclusion of the (relatively short) `post_id` column in the index was an attempt to make it a *covering* index for the query. (As RickJames points out in his comment, I believe he's right, the prefix lengths prevent the index from being used as a covering index.)

With this index defined, the index on just the singleton `meta_key(191)` would be redundant.

As an alternative, you might consider swapping the positions of the first two columns in the index, depending on the cardinality of the values (how selective a particular value is.) If you have tens of thousands of different values in `meta_value`, but only a few dozen `meta_key` values, then maybe:

```
 ... ON (`meta_value`(10), `meta_key`(191), `post_id`)
```

<strike>We'd expect EXPLAIN output to show "Using index", meaning that the query can be satisfied entirely from the index, with no need to lookup pages from the underlying table.</strike>

We'd expect that MySQL would be able to make use of that index to satisfy the predicates (equality comparisons of the `meta_value` and `meta_key` columns).

With the original query and indexes, MySQL has to access the pages in the underlying table to check the values of other column. That is, if it uses the `meta_value` index, it still has to lookup the page that has the row, so it can check the `meta_key` value.

And I don't think there's any reasonable way for MySQL to use the index on just a prefix length of 1. Values of `'12'` and `'195/55R16'`, or any string with a leading character of `1` is going to have the same entry in the index, and that could be a whole lot of repeated values in the index.  (All the values "starting with 1" are going to have the same index value), and MySQL is going to have to lookup in the table to verify that the actual value is actually "equal to 1", and not some other value that "starts with 1".

Comment: Prefixing makes `Using index` impossible -- not all of the values are in the index.